# Read from non blocking socketChannel to Protobuf

Tags: java, protocol-buffers, nio

I'm trying to create simple server-client app using Java NIO.

Here are my Protobuf classes:

```
message ArrRequest {
  int32 n = 1;
  repeated int32 array = 2;
}

message ArrResponse {
  int32 n = 1;
  repeated int32 array = 2;
}
```

On client, I send messages in a blocking manner to server using Protobuf.

```
try (Socket socket = new Socket("localhost", Constant.PORT)) {
            for (int i = 0; i < numberOfRequestsPerClient; i++) {
                List<Integer> arr = new ArrayList<>();
                Random r = new Random();
                for (int j = 0; j < numberOfArrayElements; j++) {
                    arr.add(r.nextInt());
                }
                var request = ArrRequest.newBuilder()
                        .setN(numberOfArrayElements)
                        .addAllArray(arr)
                        .build();
                request.writeDelimitedTo(socket.getOutputStream());
```

Then I want to get this messages as ArrRequest on the server side.

```
client.configureBlocking(false); -- important


                selector.select();
                Set<SelectionKey> keys = selector.selectedKeys();
                Iterator<SelectionKey> iterator = keys.iterator();
                while (iterator.hasNext()) {
                    SelectionKey key = iterator.next();
                    ClientData data = (ClientData) key.attachment();

                    if (key.isReadable()) {
                        int bytesRead = data.socket.read(data.buffer); // socket is non blocking
```

I read the data into the buffer, several bytes at a time.

So my question is, when should I stop?

**When I can make the ArrRequest out of byteBuffer? And how?** How to know the side of the ArrRequest in bytes?

Answer (score 0):

It seems that you can find out the serialized size of your ArrRequest using the getSerializedSize method.
So you can send that before the serialized ArrRequest to the server as shown in the following example:

```
var request = ArrRequest.newBuilder()
                        .setN(numberOfArrayElements)
                        .addAllArray(arr)
                        .build();
int length = request.getSerializedSize();
ByteBuffer bb = ByteBuffer.allocate(4);
bb.putInt(length);
bb.flip();
OutputStream os = socket.getOutputStream();
os.write(bb.array());
request.writeDelimitedTo(os);
```

Then on the server side you can read into a buffer. When you have 4, or greater bytes, you can get the first 4 bytes as an integer, which is the expect length of the next serialized ArrRequest. Then you can keep reading into the buffer until you have greater or equal to the length.

If you want the server to support multiple clients then you will need to create a context, per client, to hold a ByteBuffer of the the accumulated bytes for each client as you might not have all the bytes available to deserialize the ArrRequest on a single readable key.